# Java: after jar is removed, class is still loaded

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I was trying to reproduce a bug where, a jar is updated (via rsync on a linux box) and then a `NoClassDefFoundError` was thrown. The updated jar was unchanged, but I was thinking about the fact the file was transferring while the class was loading...

I'm now trying to reproduce the bug.

My application start with a classpath of only one jar (`/opt/test/myjar.jar`)

The others jar are inside a directory on the same path of myjar.jar (`/opt/test/lib/mylib.jar`).

The library is registered into the `myjar.jar` `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with this text

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: FB
Class-Path: lib/mylib.jar
```

Now I scripted some code for waiting some seconds, then load some class with `Class.forName("mylib.MyClass")`.

Then I will setup the folder, start the java runtime and then delete the `lib/mylib.jar` file, and wait for the `Class.forName` to fail.

And the code was running fine. I was expecting a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Then I rerun the code, and a `NoClassDefFoundError` was thrown.

Then I readded the `mylib.jar` to the `lib` directory, rerun, all ok.

Then I rerun the code with `-verbose:class`, deleted the `lib/mylib.jar` and then this log appeared.

```
[Loaded mylib.MyClass from file:/opt/test/lib/mylib.jar`]
```

So the class loading was happening after the jar deletion. I don't understand why this work.
And no other classes were loaded from `lib/mylib.jar` before.

Jdk used is OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 1.8.0_302-b08)

I don't understand how the JVM can load a class from a file I just deleted. I think maybe the JVM cache those files somewhere (mabye cause they are registered inside the `MANIFEST.MF`).

Have anyone an idea of this behavior??

Ps. I tested this exact procedure, but with real jar and classes. If no one have an idea on the why, I can build an test project.

Comment: Where did you run this: Class.forName("mylib.MyClass")?

Comment: from the main class (located into the myjar.jar).

Comment: It probably can load from the same classpath or same package.

Comment: mmm no, the two class are on different packages...
and another funny thing. After successfully loading the class in the mylib.jar, if I get the `mylib.MyClass` classloader, and then I look up for urls (casting it to `URLClassLoader`) the only jar referenced is `myjar.jar`, even if the class just loaded was inside `mylib.jar`. I think it all boil down to the `MANIFEST.MF`, but I need more investigation

Comment: after printing property `lmap` of the class-loader as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29814439/112033, I just see that all jar listed on the MANIFEST.MF file were present from the beginning, so that's probably why I see this behavior

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The real question should be “how can I delete a file while the JVM has opened it?” This is operating system specific. On some systems, deleting the file will fail, on others, you can delete it (it disappears from the directory) but applications having still open file handles can continue to use it until they close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a system without mandatory file locking. If you tried the same under Windows, for example, you couldn’t do neither, overwrite nor delete the .jar file.

The jar files on the class path are opened when the JVM starts and kept open during the runtime. We can demonstrate the behavior using ordinary file operations:

```java
Path p = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")),"test",".tmp");
try(FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(p,
                                 StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
  System.out.println("opened " + p);
  int rc = new ProcessBuilder("rm", "-v", p.toString()).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
  System.out.println("rm ran with rc " + rc);
  int w = ch.write(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode("test data"));
  System.out.println("wrote " + w + " bytes into " + p);
  ch.position(0);
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(w);
  do ch.read(bb); while(bb.hasRemaining());
  bb.flip();
  System.out.println("read " + bb.remaining() + " bytes, "
                   + StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.decode(bb));
}
System.out.println("closed, reopening");
try(FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(p,
                                 StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
  System.out.println("opened " + p);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
  System.out.println("Reopening " + p + ": " + ex);
}
```

prints something like

```
opened /home/tux/test722563514590118445.tmp
removed '/home/tux/test722563514590118445.tmp'
rm ran with rc 0
wrote 9 bytes into /home/tux/test722563514590118445.tmp
read 9 bytes, test data
closed, reopening
Reopening /home/tux/test722563514590118445.tmp: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/tux/test722563514590118445.tmp
```

demonstrating that after removing, we can still write and read data from the already opened file, as only the entry has been removed from the directory. The JVM is now operating on a file without a name. But as soon as this filehandle has been closed, trying to open it again will fail, as now it is really gone.

---

Overwriting the file, however, is a different thing. When opening the existing file, we access the same file and make changes perceivable.

So

```java
Path p = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")),"test",".tmp");
try(FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(p,
                                 StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
  System.out.println("opened " + p);
  int w = ch.write(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode("test data"));
  System.out.println("wrote " + w + " bytes into " + p);
  int rc = new ProcessBuilder("cp", "/proc/self/cmdline", p.toString())
      .inheritIO().start().waitFor();
  System.out.println("cp ran with rc " + rc);
  ch.position(0);
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(w);
  do ch.read(bb); while(bb.hasRemaining());
  bb.flip();
  System.out.println("read " + bb.remaining() + " bytes, "
                   + StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.decode(bb));
}
```

produces something like

```
opened /home/tux/test7100435925076742504.tmp
wrote 9 bytes into /home/tux/test7100435925076742504.tmp
cp ran with rc 0
read 9 bytes, cp/proc/
```

Showing that the `read` operation on the already open file resulted in what `cp` wrote, partially of course, as the buffer was pre-sized to what the Java application wrote. This demonstrates how overwriting an open file can cause havoc when some data has been read already and the application tries to interpret the new data according to what it knows from the old version.

---

This leads to a solution for updating a jar file without crashing the already running JVM. Delete the old jar file first, which lets the JVM run with the already opened, now-private old file, before copying the new version to the same location. From the system’s perspective, you have two different files then. The old one will cease to exist when the JVM terminates. JVMs started after the replacement will use the new version.

Comment: make sense! I have some irrational fear of deleting jars from a running jvm process, but I will definitively give it a try